# Non-linear Inductor LTSpice

Tags: inductor, ltspice, non-linear

I am trying to implement a non-linear inductor in LTSpice and to get it to saturate.

I am using the following directive between N1 and N2 as advised in the help files:

L1 N1 N2 Hc=12 Br=0.2 Bs=0.4 A=4u Lm=0.4 Lg=0.01u N=100

With a DC voltage supplied the circuit behaves as if it is purely resistive regardless of the voltage.

This is the circuit I am using.

[image]

Plot.
[image]

Is there something else that needs to be added here??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make the source a DC source.

With the DC source, LTSpice is assuming the voltage has been 10 V since \$t=-\infty\$ and all transients have settled before the simulation starts.

Make it a transient source that turns from 0 V to 10 V a few ms after the simulation starts.

Comment: Yea the delay works better. Also I had too low a resistance and it was saturating almost immediately. I increased the resistor so the current was stable and then increased when it went into saturation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use a PWL or PULSE source. In addition to what ThePhoton said, you can change the graph to an x-y source by clicking on the time axis and changing the [time axis to a signal](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/365545/how-do-i-achieve-xy-mode-on-ltspice).

[image]